# accessing nasted json objects

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to access JSON objects in JavaScript and display them in HTML table, I managed to do it but failed to display one of the columns.

[project link](http://asktechtz.com/json/hotels.php)

```
<script>
        var arrItems = [];      // THE ARRAY TO STORE JSON ITEMS.
        $.each(data.glance, function (index, value) {
            arrItems.push(value);       // PUSH THE VALUES INSIDE THE ARRAY.


        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR TABLE HEADER.
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {
            for (var key in arrItems[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < arrItems.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            data
            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = arrItems[0];
                tabCell.innerHTML = arrItems[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("daytoday");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
    });
```

Also, am trying to access images and display them in slider but not sure how to access the nested image object,

**Question:** Can someone show me how can I access the images?

[Image slider page](http://asktechtz.com/json/accommodation.php)

```
 <script>

$('img[class="logo"]').attr('src',data.logo);
$('div[class="header_bg"]').css('background-image', 'url(' + data.topbanner + ')');
//alert(JSON.stringify(data.property_images));
var countDown=0;
$.each(data.property_information,function(key,value){
  if(key!='NGORONGORO SOPA LODGE'){
  //alert(key);
    var cont="";
    var innerDivTop ='<div class="centre-container">'
                        +'<div  class="page-content">'
                        +'<div class="flex">'
                         +'<div class="body" style="width: 100%;">'
                          +'<div class="content-block"><h2 style="font-weight:bold">'+key+'</h2>'
                           +'<div class="flexslider">'
                              +'<div class="arrow-next" data-role="'+countDown+'"></div>'
                               +'<div class="arrow-back" data-role="'+countDown+'"></div>'
                                +'<ul class="services dynmic_'+countDown+'" >';



    for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++) {

      if(i==0) {
       // alert(value[i]);
       // console.log(value[i]);

       cont +='<li style="display: block;"><img src="'+value[i]+'" alt="" style="width:1088px;height:430px;" ></li>';

      } else {
        cont +='<li><img src="'+value[i]+'" alt="" style="width:1088px;height:430px;"></li>';

      } 
    }

        var innerDivBot='</ul>'
                          +'</div></div></div></div></div></div>';
 $('#contentRpt').append(innerDivTop+cont+innerDivBot);
 countDown +=1;
 }
});
```

Here is my Json data example :

```
 { "glance": {
"Day 1": {
  "location": "ARUSHA",
  "property": "THE ARUSHA HOTEL"
},
"Day 2": {
  "location": "TARANGIRE NATIONAL PARK",
  "property": "TARANGIRE SAFARI LODGE"
},
"Day 3": {
  "location": "LAKE MANYARA NATIONAL PARK",
  "property": "LAKE MANYARA HOTEL"
},
"Day 4": {
  "location": "SERENGETI NATIONAL PARK",
  "property": "SERENGETI SOPA LODGE"
},
"Day 5": {
  "location": "SERENGETI NATIONAL PARK",
  "property": "SERENGETI SOPA LODGE"
},
"Day 6": {
  "location": "SERENGETI NATIONAL PARK",
  "property": "SERENGETI SOPA LODGE"
},
"Day 7": {
  "location": "NGORONGORO CONSERVATION AREA AUTHORITY",
  "property": "NGORONGORO SOPA LODGE"
}
 }, "property_information": {
"THE ARUSHA HOTEL": {
  "description": "Arusha\u2019s supreme boutique hotel offering first class accommodation and service, surrounded by the history of bygone eras. The hotel boasts the finest location in the heart of Arusha, in the tranquil surroundings of its own tropical gardens.\r\n\r\nThe Arusha Hotel boasts 86 elegantly appointed rooms included 4 Suites, 25 Executive Deluxe rooms and 57 Superior Rooms. Professionally managed, we ensure the needs of every guest are carried out with East African charm and warmth.\r\n\r\n",
  "images": [
    "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/the_arusha_hotel\/dining_parachichi.jpg",
    "http:\/\/asktechtzco.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/the_arusha_hotel\/images-30.jpeg",
    "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/the_arusha_hotel\/room_superior1.jpg"
  ]
},
"TARANGIRE SAFARI LODGE": {
  "description": "Built on top of a high bluff with a breathtaking panorama, our lodge is superbly located in Tarangire National Park, providing one of the best views in Africa.\r\n\r\nCarving out the landscape below the lodge is Tarangire River, a favourite watering place, which attracts impressive numbers and variety of game. The scene unfolds before you while lounging on the outdoor patio, allowing you to appreciate Tarangire\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&#039;s diverse wildlife without ever leaving the lodge.",
  "images": [
    "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/tarangire_safari_lodge\/images-31.jpeg",
    "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/tarangire_safari_lodge\/images-32.jpeg",
    "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/tarangire_safari_lodge\/images-33.jpeg"
  ]
}
```

}}

Comment: How's your Json data look like ? add a sample to your question

Comment: @R.K.Saini i have added sample json data

Comment: So, you need to show day column as first column of table

Comment: yes that is correct i need to show a column called DAY as first column  @R.K.Saini

Comment: I seen you project link http://asktechtz.com/json/hotels.php and I found there is one **undefined table variable** appending to div container , here is that line **var divContainer = document.getElementById("daytoday");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);** just comment it out **divContainer.appendChild(table);** and run  you will able to see images above  table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to show a property name so you a nested loop here first to access object property and its value and then a second loop to extract values from value you extract in outer loop.

Try like this

```
$(function() {
  table = $("<table></table>").appendTo("#daytoday");
  table.append("<tr><th>DAY</th><th> LOCATION </th><th> HOTEL </th></tr>")
  $.each(data.glance, function(index, value) {
    row = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(table);
    $("<td></td>").appendTo(row).html(index);

    $.each(value, function(i, v) {
      $("<td></td>").appendTo(row).html(v);
    });
  });

});
```

```js
var data = {
  "glance": {
    "Day 1": {
      "location": "ARUSHA",
      "property": "THE ARUSHA HOTEL"
    },
    "Day 2": {
      "location": "TARANGIRE NATIONAL PARK",
      "property": "TARANGIRE SAFARI LODGE"
    },
    "Day 3": {
      "location": "LAKE MANYARA NATIONAL PARK",
      "property": "LAKE MANYARA HOTEL"
    },
    "Day 4": {
      "location": "SERENGETI NATIONAL PARK",
      "property": "SERENGETI SOPA LODGE"
    },
    "Day 5": {
      "location": "SERENGETI NATIONAL PARK",
      "property": "SERENGETI SOPA LODGE"
    },
    "Day 6": {
      "location": "SERENGETI NATIONAL PARK",
      "property": "SERENGETI SOPA LODGE"
    },
    "Day 7": {
      "location": "NGORONGORO CONSERVATION AREA AUTHORITY",
      "property": "NGORONGORO SOPA LODGE"
    }
  },
  "property_information": {
    "THE ARUSHA HOTEL": {
      "description": "Arusha\u2019s supreme boutique hotel offering first class accommodation and service, surrounded by the history of bygone eras. The hotel boasts the finest location in the heart of Arusha, in the tranquil surroundings of its own tropical gardens.\r\n\r\nThe Arusha Hotel boasts 86 elegantly appointed rooms included 4 Suites, 25 Executive Deluxe rooms and 57 Superior Rooms. Professionally managed, we ensure the needs of every guest are carried out with East African charm and warmth.\r\n\r\n",
      "images": [
        "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/the_arusha_hotel\/dining_parachichi.jpg",
        "http:\/\/asktechtzco.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/the_arusha_hotel\/images-30.jpeg",
        "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/the_arusha_hotel\/room_superior1.jpg"
      ]
    },
    "TARANGIRE SAFARI LODGE": {
      "description": "Built on top of a high bluff with a breathtaking panorama, our lodge is superbly located in Tarangire National Park, providing one of the best views in Africa.\r\n\r\nCarving out the landscape below the lodge is Tarangire River, a favourite watering place, which attracts impressive numbers and variety of game. The scene unfolds before you while lounging on the outdoor patio, allowing you to appreciate Tarangire\\\\\\\\\\\\\\&#039;s diverse wildlife without ever leaving the lodge.",
      "images": [
        "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/tarangire_safari_lodge\/images-31.jpeg",
        "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/tarangire_safari_lodge\/images-32.jpeg",
        "http:\/\/asktechtz.co.tz\/spear22\/\/images\/demo\/accommodation\/tarangire_safari_lodge\/images-33.jpeg"
      ]
    }
  }
};
$(function() {
  table = $("<table></table>").appendTo("#daytoday");
  table.append("<tr><th>DAY</th><th> LOCATION </th><th> HOTEL </th></tr>")
  $.each(data.glance, function(index, value) {
    row = $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(table);
    $("<td></td>").appendTo(row).html(index);

    $.each(value, function(i, v) {
      $("<td></td>").appendTo(row).html(v);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="daytoday">

</div>
```

**SECOND QUESTION :**

For your second question you need to loop through the image property of valve 
so you need to call your loop on value.images

So change your inner for loop like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < value.images.length; i++) {

    if (i == 0) {
        // alert(value[i]);
        // console.log(value[i]);
        cont += '<li style="display: block;"><img src="' + value.images[i] + '" alt="" style="width:1088px;height:430px;" ></li>';

    } else {
        cont += '<li><img src="' + value.images[i] + '" alt="" style="width:1088px;height:430px;"></li>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @R.K.Saini  . This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Do you have an idea how i can access images as per my second question?

Comment: In your second question you want to add image slide to your slider right ?

Comment: yes sure ,i want to display the description on top then below to add images on slider .But am not sure how to access the images because they are nested.

Comment: Hey, is it wok for you ?

Comment: Thank a lot everything now works pefectly.  Thanks again